# maths symbols- don't appear

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I have a problem with maths symbols. 
The \leg dosen't appear in PDF.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\newcommand\eqcomment[1]{\fbox{\makebox[4cm]{#1}}}

\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{ntxsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\simp}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{74}
```

Comment: please fix your example so that it is an example of the problem you are asking about, it does not include any math typesetting, make it a complete document and say what result you expect.

Comment: What's `\leg`? Never heard about it.

Comment: @egreg pull the other one

Comment: Somthing like this =<.

Comment: I don't know what I should do :c

Comment: do you mean `\leq`, with a `q` at the end?

Comment: @Saizou no please edit your question so that it has a complete document that does not work as you expect, currently you ask about a command that is not defined and show lots of code loading tikz and other packages that are probably not relevant but no code related to your question

Comment: Thread to colse, I've solved problem.
Instaed of \leg should be \le 
I don't know why my assistence promts \leg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by OP (see comments)